# allow ng-drag element to be dragged in one direction only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable.

```
<div  ng-drag="true" 
ng-drop="true" ng-drag-start="example($data,$event)"  >
</div>
```

The div is to be dropped right there where is was dragged from and it works just fine. However, I want it to be dragged in y direction only.

How do I do this?Using additional custom directive?Function? controller?

Also, I want the element to be dragged upto a maximum distance based on size of the screen may be, how do I add this constraint?

I found this https://github.com/fumitoito/angular-draggable but I need it to come back when it is dropped anywhere else except for drop area which is none in my case and It does not help with coming back thing.

Comment: Take a look at [Nicolas Bevacqua's Angular Dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/angular-dragula). For sure, it's by far the best draggable library out there.

Comment: I am not able to drag the element with dragula directive. Any tips?

Comment: That did not help . Can any one help me modify ngDraggable in order to stop movements in direction other than vertical?

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is a somewhat old thread, I had the same requirement and finally resorted to modifying ngDraggable.js. For me the change was simple. The left position of the element to drag is always 0, so I only changed the lines that set the _tx variable in the `onmove` and `onlongpress` functions in the `ngDrag` directive:

```
if (_centerAnchor) {
    _tx = 0; // _tx = _mx - element.centerX - _dragOffset.left;
    _ty = _my - element.centerY - _dragOffset.top;
} else {
    _tx = 0; //_mx - _mrx - _dragOffset.left;
    _ty = _my - _mry - _dragOffset.top;
}
```

If you use `ng-drag-clone` you'll need to make a similar change in the `onDragMove` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

If this is anything like Dragula, then you can try to find out what class the clone inherits.  For example, in Dragula, there is a new element that looks just like the object you're dragging with the class .gu-mirror.  Observing this element, I noticed that as I dragged it, the "left" and "top" styles were modified based on where I was dragging the element.  So, to make sure I was only able to drag the element up and down, I locked the "left" style by setting it to "left: 0px!important" in CSS.  See if this helps in your case.  Granted, it's not Dragula, but I believe the approach will be very similar.